# Amazon Athena does not preserve property names of struct correctly in an array when reading parquet files

Tags: parquet, amazon-athena

I'm trying to read parquet files that include a property typed as array of struct from Amazon Athena. This property actually looks like this:

```
|-- arrival_pages: array
|    |-- element: struct
|    |    |-- hierarchy: long
|    |    |-- id: long
|    |    |-- recency: long
(partial output from pyspark's dataframe.printSchema)
```

To read the property, I defined a column with this type in Athena:

```
arrival_pages array<struct<id: bigint, hierarchy: bigint, recency: bigint>>
```

Any select query involving this column executes successfully, but resulting struct does NOT preserve its property names correspondence. That is, property names are mapped from parquet to Athena like this:

```
(parquet -> Athena)
hierarchy -> id
id -> hierarchy
recency -> recency
```

When I set random property names in table definition on Athena, which is for example:

```
arrival_pages array<struct<foo: bigint, bar: bigint, baz: bigint>>
```

the query executes **successfully** and resulting mapping looks like this:

```
(parquet -> Athena)
hierarchy -> foo
id -> bar
recency -> baz
```

So it seems that Athena just reads the properties of struct in predefined order, and map them into the desired struct regardless of what property names it has. Is this a intended behavior or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is because of [a bug in older version of Hive](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12619), which is used by Athena to manage its metadata. This bug has already been fixed in the latest version of Hive, but Athena is still using an older version. And there is no announcement about upgrading at the moment.

Fortunatelly I'm able to easily modify parquet files' structure, so I'm going to make it flatter so that I can avoid using struct type in Athena.